# Как указать правильный селектор для вставки части контента из одной страницы сайта в другую

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: скрин консоли][image: скрин]Нужно вставить контент (блок div) с одной страницы на другую. Подскажите пожалуйста, как указать правильный селектор чтобы в элемент `#txt_8` вставился `div` который вложен в элемент `#8421775`.

```
$("#txt_8").load("https://pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog #8421775 > div");
```

Так не работает.

Comment: Как я понял вы пытаетесь загрузить часть контента с другого сайта и получаете ошибку "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." в консоли, верно?

Comment: нет. ошибки нет. выводиться пустой блок #8421775 хотя на странице с которой я его вытаскиваю в нем лежит div с текстом

Comment: если я указываю id вложенного div вместо родителя, всё работает

Comment: не могу найти на странице https://pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog элемента с id 8421775

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: откройте в режиме инкогнито страницу, в отображении для обычных пользователей там нет таких блоков, у вас на скрине видно какую-то админ-панель

Comment: я прошу прощения(уже мозг кипит) на сайте этих элементов нет  я всё делаю в тестовой теме

Comment: Идентификатор должен обязательно начинаться с латинского символа и может содержать в себе латинские буквы (A–Z, a–z), цифры (0–9), символ дефиса (-) и подчеркивания (_).

Comment: непонятно почему $("#txt_8").load("https://pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog #562531"); - работает, а если #8421775 то вставляет пустой блок

Comment: можем ли мы получить от вас response функции load("https://pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog #8421775") ?

Comment: $("#txt_8").load( "pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog #8421775", function( response, status, xhr ) { console.log($.parseJSON(response)) });

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: выше написал как

Comment: И $("#txt_8").load( "pitermotors.ru/blogs/blog #8421775 > div", function( response, status, xhr ) { console.log($.parseJSON(response)) });

Comment: там целая простыня(часть на скрине). я так понимаю это вся страница

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0